Maximal differential structure on a finite dimensional vector space
Let $M$ be a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $N$. For a basis $\beta = \{v_1, ..., v_N\}$ of $M$, define the map $X_\beta : \mathbb{R}^N \to M$ by $X_\beta(a_1, ..., a_N) = a_1 v_1 + ... + a_N v_N$. I know how to show that $\{(X_\beta, \mathbb{R}^N)\}$ is a differential structure on $M$. Actually I don't know if this is a maximal one. I suspect that $\mathcal{A} = \{(X_\beta, \mathbb{R}^N) : \beta \text{ is a basis on }M\}$ is maximal, but I don't know how to prove it, that is, given $\mathcal{B} =\{(X_\alpha, U_{\alpha})\}_\alpha$ another structure of $M$, how to show that $\mathcal{B}  \subset \mathcal{A} ?$
